# How to decode values in Redis database?

Tags: redis, geocoding

I stored the geoset in redis database with GEOADD command as -

```
GEOADD city 13.361389 38.115556 'paris'
```

and able to get the stored values with following command -

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE city 0 -1
```

but I am getting response as -

```
 1) "1"
 2) "3484047800163752"
 3) "10"
 4) "3484047800163752"
 5) "2"
 6) "3484047800163752"
```

Can anybody please help me to find out decoded values like 13.361389 38.115556

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation, specifically that of the [`GEOPOS`](http://redis.io/commands/geopos) command:

```
redis> GEOPOS city 1 2 3
```

Comment: Ok, I admit that this doesn't make sense - GEOADD and GEOPOS were added together in 3.2. Which Redis are you using?

Comment: okay @Itamar , I am using 2.8.4 , I'll upgrade my version and will let you know if above solution works or not.Thanks much.

Comment: do you know any link to update Redis version ? I tried this http://tosbourn.com/install-latest-version-redis-ubuntu/ but it is not working